# Printing The Result of a Division Between Two Doubles only if the second value is different from zero

Tags: java, divide-by-zero

I'm trying to make a Java program that takes two doubles in input, divides them and then prints out the result of the division. However, if the second double that it takes as input is zero, I want the program to keep asking the user to insert another number, for as long as the user gives as input to the program a number that is different from zero.

I tried to translate into Java code this idea, but I've never really gotten the result I wanted. So far, the code I've written is the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoubleDivision {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the first number that you want to divide: ");
        double numerator = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the second number that you want to divide: ");
        double denominator = scan.nextDouble();
        
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter the second number that you want to divide: ");
            double denominator1 = scan.nextDouble();
        } while (denominator == 0);
                
        double fraction = numerator/denominator;
        System.out.println("The result of the division is: " + fraction);
        
            
        scan.close();       
            
    }
}
```

I tried to use a do-while loop, but I'm afraid I somehow failed at implementing it properly.
Is there anyone who might be able to give me some piece of advice? I'm kinda a beginner in the coding world.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You used another variable to compare the scanner result, denominator1 is set but then the other variable is used for the do while loop

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the first number that you want to divide: ");
            double numerator = scan.nextDouble();
            double denominator;
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter the second number that you want to divide: ");
                denominator = scan.nextDouble();
            } while (denominator == 0);

            double fraction = numerator/denominator;
            System.out.println("The result of the division is: " + fraction);
            scan.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close.  Here are my test results.

```
Enter the first number that you want to divide: 
1
Enter the second number that you want to divide: 
0
Enter the second number that you want to divide: 
3
The result of the division is: 0.3333333333333333
```

Here's the code with the changes made.  A while loop would have been more natural, but I kept your do-while loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoubleDivision {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the first number that you want to divide: ");
        double numerator = scan.nextDouble();

        double denominator;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter the second number that you want to divide: ");
            denominator = scan.nextDouble();
        } while (denominator == 0);

        double fraction = numerator / denominator;
        System.out.println("The result of the division is: " + fraction);

        scan.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake in your do-while is that you are reading the value into a different variable (i.e. `denominator1`) than the one you are testing (`denominator`).  In fact, you are using a variable whose scope is limited to the body of that do-while.  Simple solution is to use the variable you had already defined for the denominator.

```
double denominator = 0.0;
do {
  System.out.println("Enter the second number that you want to divide: ");
  denominator = scan.nextDouble();
} while (denominator == 0.0);
```

I would suggest that you modify the prompts to inform the user that they are entering the numerator and denominator respectively.  IF they enter a 0.0 for denominator then tell them what's wrong before repeating the prompt.  In this example, I put it in a separate method.

```
private void readDenominator() {
  System.out.println("Enter the denominator: ");
  denominator = scan.nextDouble();
  while (denominator == 0.0) {
    System.out.println("Cannot divide by zero.  Enter the denominator: ");
    denominator = scan.nextDouble();
  }
}
```